# Session doesn't get expired in JSF 2.2

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2

Im facing problem expiring session in JSF 2.2, I tried many solutions but in vain.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
```

and

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

I checked bean with both scopes 'View' and 'Session'. Im not using JSF scope annotations rather our application architecture restrict us to use Spring scope like @scope("session") and i created view scope bean (according to: http://comdynamics.net/blog/109/spring3-jsf2-view-scope/) and register with Spring scopes and used like @scope("view"). It doesn't throw any exception, calls bean logout code and navigate to login page but after logging out when i try to access homepage or any other page it shows all session data even in different browser.

It was working fine with JSF 1.2, I upgraded JSF from 1.2 to 2.2 and now its not working since.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: can you try ((HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false)).invalidate()

Comment: Tried this too but same result.

Comment: @erencan: Why would that ever make difference? `ExternalContext` delegates straight to it.

Comment: @BalusC sorry, i was missing  it.